# Choosing allowed methods from Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstract-class

I have an abstract class with methods with logic.
Then i have childs but not all childs can have all methods from the abstract class. I have been thinking of a design pattern that allows me to keep the logic instead of using interfaces but can't think of anyhting other then using a static class with methods. But it would make my code very sloppy.

Another way of formulating my question is: How do i use interfaces with logic in them...

```
public abstract class Company
{
    public virtual void Dowork1()
    {
        //logic
    }

    public virtual void Dowork2()
    {
        //logic
    }

    public virtual void Dowork3()
    {
        //logic
    }
}

public class ItCompany : Company
{
    //DoWork2 NOT callable
}

public class ManagementCompany : Company
{
    //DoWork1 NOT callable
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pillar of object oriented programming is [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In practical terms this means that any implementation of `Company` need to implement all the methods. I.e. one implementation of a company should be possible to substitute for any other.

You seem to be concerned about *implementation inheritance*, i.e. allow any of the implementations to reuse the same logic without the need to reimplement it. This can be problematic since it couples the base class to the derived classes. However, you should be able to do what you describe by making the implementations protected.

```
public abstract class Company
{
    protected virtual void DoworkImpl1()
    {
        //logic
    }

    protected virtual void DoworkImpl2()
    {
        //logic
    }

    protected virtual void DoworkImpl3()
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

This lets each implementation define what parts they want to expose:

```
public class ItCompany : Company
{
    public void Dowork1() => DoworkImpl1();
    public void Dowork3() => DoworkImpl3();
}
```

You may also add different interfaces for each type of company if you want to, as shown in other answers. However, if `Company` does not expose any public methods, you cannot really do anything with a object of the base type, except check what specific type it is, and this is often indicative of a problem in the class design. I would recommend reading Eric Lipperts article on [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for some perspective.

A possible replacement is to move logic to static methods, for example using extension methods or [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods):

```
public static class CompanyHelpers{
    public static void Dowork1(this ICompany company){
         // Logic
    }
}
```

This can be very useful with well designed interfaces that expose a minimal set of functions, and provides most extra functionality via extension methods. See LINQ for an example. But it may or may not be applicable in your specific situation.

Comment: exposing it with protected isthe way i am going. Exactly what i was looking for, thanks! Is this a known design pattern? What is the name of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the problem from the wrong side. Let me rename your methods to make it more clear.

```
public abstract class Company
{
    public virtual void ManagementWork()
    {
        //logic
    }

    public virtual void ItWork()
    {
        //logic
    }

    public virtual void BuildCompany()
    {
        //general logic
    }
}

public class ItCompany : Company
{
    //ManagementWork NOT callable
}

public class ManagementCompany : Company
{
    //ItWork NOT callable
}
```

It would be better this way

```
public abstract class Company
{

    public virtual void BuildCompany()
    {
        //general logic
    }
}

public class ItCompany : Company
{
    public virtual void ItWork()
    {
        //logic
    }
}

public class ManagementCompany : Company
{
    public virtual void ManagementWork()
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I have many companies where some of them have all 3, some of them only 1 etc....

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the better way :

```
interface IDoableWorkOne
{
void DoWork1();
}

interface IDoableWorkTwo
{
void DoWork2();
}

interface IDoableWorkThree
{
void DoWork3();
}

interface ICompany
{
  //Other Company Shared Logics
}

public class ManagementCompany: IDoableWorkTwo, IDoableWorkThree, ICompany
{
/// Do your Business
}

public class ItCompany : IDoableWorkOne, IDoableWorkThree, ICompany
{
/// Do Your Business
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The interfaces have no logic so it would result in having to copy paste big logic

Comment: @Joben if you write about ICompany interface, it is just a word usage. OP could add anything what he need in it. As an example OP can add an Id and Name, a different Method something like override string ToString() etc.  And theoritically, every method is a logic -logical codes- which does the needed jobs.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stick with inheritance in such situation makes me think that you are trying to use the wrong tool for your job.

You may achieve code reuse by favoring [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and refactor your code as follow:

```
public sealed class Company
{
    public void Dowork1()
    {
        //logic
    }

    public void Dowork2()
    {
        //logic
    }

    public void Dowork3()
    {
        //logic
    }
}

public sealed class ItCompany
{
    private readonly Company _company;

    public ItCompany(Company company) => _company = company;

    //Call DoWork1 and DoWork3 whenever you want from _company
}

public sealed class ManagementCompany
{    
    private readonly Company _company;

    public ManagementCompany (Company company) => _company = company;

    //Call DoWork2 and DoWork3 whenever you want from _company
}
```

This code has the same benefits of code reuse than inheritance but without the burden of trying to hide normally public inherited methods.

Also you can be sure that no one ever can alter `Company`'s behavior (such a central piece of logic for you) since the class is `sealed`, unlike solutions trying to stick with inheritance that allow overriding `DoworkX()` methods.